# How to add hyperlink control items to a ASP.net ListBox control?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add multiple hyperlink control items to a asp.net listbox control. I have written below code but it is not generating required output.

```
lstBoxAttachments.Controls.Add(new HyperLink() { Text = someText, NavigateUrl = someURL });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list box cannot contain hyperlinks. This is a limitation of HTML, not specific to asp.net.

Try using a repeater control instead.